# Apache logs are updated only after service restart

Tags: php, apache, logging, window

A webserver is running `PHP` hosted on `Apache 2.4` on a `Windows`machine.

I can only see the `error.log` file getting updated after I restart `Apache` service. What could cause this?

Comment: It sounds like your vhost might have a custom logging location.  That would account for only global messages appearing in the main error.log.  Look for a line like this in your vhost definition: `ErrorLog /path/to/custom/error.log`

Comment: It is set in my `httpd.conf` like this `ErrorLog "logs/error.log"`. Notice that I do see all the logs I expect, except that I can only force them to appear via an `Apache` service restart.

Comment: This may also have something to do with your log reader. If you are reading the log in notepad it may just be lagging behind instead of refreshing the file.

Comment: I'm reading logs from `notepad++`. I do not thing that is the issue.